# input string cannot be parsed to integer in java

Tags: java, xml, collections, numberformatexception

i have following numbers saved in array (readed from XML files):

```
100000000000008261
100000000000008266
100000000000008267
100000000000008268
```

The SeqNrList is filled by this:

```
ArrayList SeqNrList = new ArrayList<>();
SeqNrList.add(doc.getElementsByTagName("SequenceNumber").item(0).getTextContent());
```

I've try to get the minimum and maximum value with following code:

```
int seqsizemin = Integer.parseInt((String) Collections.min(SeqNrList));
int seqsizemax = Integer.parseInt((String) Collections.max(SeqNrList));
```

Also, i've try'd with following:

```
int seqsizemin = Integer.valueOf((String) Collections.min(SeqNrList));
int seqsizemax = Integer.valueOf((String) Collections.max(SeqNrList));
```

But i got only following error when i run my script:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100000000000008261"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at ReadXMLFile.main(ReadXMLFile.java:117)
```

Is there any special function needed, why i cant save

Comment: the numbers are probably too large for Integers to handle. Try using Long class instead.

Comment: `long min = SeqNrList.stream().mapToLong(Long::parseLong).min();` (Your idea would have worked, when the numbers indeed all have the same number of digits.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the JavaDoc of `Integer#parseInt()`:

> An exception of type NumberFormatException is thrown if any of the following situations occurs: [...] **The value represented by the string is not a value of type int**.

Any number which can not be parsed into an `int` is invalid.

In your case is the number `100000000000008261` larger than the `32-Bit Integer` of Java. That's why you're getting the error.

To go arround this, have a look at `Long#parseLong()`:

```
long seqsizemin = Long.parseLong((String) Collections.min(SeqNrList));
long seqsizemax = Long.parseLong((String) Collections.max(SeqNrList));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that integer data types can hold value requiring up to 32 bits, the values from your example require more than 32 bits to be represented, using `Long.parseLong` could give you the value represented as `long` and in case you need to handle bigger values, take a look to `BigInteger`.